# Total Value based on Group cross reference? (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I'd like to query a couple of tables to come up with a total sum of the value of a set of items, but with the price being dependent on data in another cell range, then grouping it based on category.

For example, say I have a data table containing name, category, and price of some grocery items. Another table I store my current inventory of groceries. I would like to calculate the value of, say, all my fruit.

Here is an editable example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y2fLgwrsMr-dWojy3uYZ1Qs2U01AP3RlT_PI2txwZRE/edit?usp=sharing

Not sure the best way to approach this?

Thanks for any guidance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Use `VLOOKUP` for searching the right item of your inventory and then multiply it with the value of the product you made the search with. For more info about `VLOOKUP` check [this documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en).

`=VLOOKUP(E3,$A$3:$C$11,3,FALSE)*F3`

With these values, create a column next to Quantity indicating the total price for each product (as show in the picture below). Then, create another column with the Type of each item performing a similar `VLOOKUP` formula:

`=VLOOKUP(E3,$A$3:$C$11,2,FALSE)`

Finally, use these two columns as input ranges to apply a `SUMIF` formula for adding up the items of each group:

`=SUMIF(H3:H6,"Fruit",G3:G6)`

For more info about `SUMIF` check [this documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en).

[image: demonstration]

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Hi @Mateo-Randwolf, thanks for replying!  I'm actually trying to get the sum of the entire group of, say for example "Fruit"... So, my formula should be looking at my inventory, then cross referencing each item with the group that it belongs to, and then multiply the quantity by the price for each item, and then add everything up together for a Group total value. (I only have apples and bananas Grouped to "Fruit" in the example presented, but imagine if there we dozens or hundreds of different items.) Thanks for your help so far, any further guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi ! So the values shown in the picture are basically the multiplication of your inventory quantity with the price per pound (*3.92 for bananas, 5.94 for apples, etc*). For calculating the total cost of all the items you can simply add the whole range of *the multplications we made*. In this case it would be ```=SUM(E14:E17)```. Does this solve your question ? If so I will add it to the solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the help. I'm trying to aggregate the sums by different groups.. So in this example, I have "Fruit", "Vegetable", and "Meat" as different groups. I'm trying to get a sum of the value of just items in inventory that match the Fruit group. Does that make sense? It might help if I add a few more example entries to the Inventory data range. I'll do that to help visualize.

Comment: Hi ! I have edited my answer to satisfy your question. Let me know if this is what you wanted :D